# What's `//` in Vyper?

Tags: vyper

I'm doing some division in vyper (v0.4.0b), but I keep getting this error:

```py
InvalidOperation: Cannot perform decimal division on uint256

  (hint: did you mean `(convert(price, uint256) * ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION) * amount // PRECISION`?)
```

When my original statement has a single backslash.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Vyper **v0.4.0** replaces the normal (*single*) division operator with a *double slash* (`//`) division operator, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/7d466a67d84ba1139cee5483bf692de90d3b2252/examples/tokens/ERC4626.vy#L94), [here](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/7d466a67d84ba1139cee5483bf692de90d3b2252/examples/market_maker/on_chain_market_maker.vy#L32) and [here](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/7d466a67d84ba1139cee5483bf692de90d3b2252/examples/tokens/ERC4626.vy#L112).